# Why are my paths to Ruby and Gems causing errors with a fresh Yeoman build?

Tags: ruby, angularjs, sass, yeoman

I'm using Yeoman to build an Angular.js app. I've opted for it to include support for Sass and Compass. But when I build with Grunt, it fails because it can't find Ruby to compile the scss files.

Here are the errors I'm seeing:

```
 Warning: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem compass (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
        from /usr/bin/compass:18 Use --force to continue.
```

I have no idea where to start with this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have compass?

Try to write in the terminal:

```
compass -v
```

If there is not, you should install these gems:

```
sudo gem install compass
```

Comment: You are right, which is a relief, and totally embarrassing. Thank you!